# Display posts belonging to child term

Tags: terms, php

I would like to list out the child terms related to the taxonomy archive and then list posts belonging to the child terms below the term name.

I currently have the following code which successfully lists out the child terms.

```
$this_term = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
'parent' => $this_term->term_id,
'orderby' => 'slug',
'hide_empty' => false
 );

$child_terms = get_terms( $this_term->taxonomy, $args );
echo '<ul>';

foreach ($child_terms as $term) {

//List the child topics 
echo '<li><h3><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $this_term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</h3></a></li>'; 

// Try to list the contained posts (DOES NOT WORK)
?> <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><div><?php

 }//end foreach
  echo '</ul>';
```

However, I need it to then display the permalinks for articles that belong to that child term. My current method of using 'the_permalink' just returns the same post in each topic.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You will need to create a custom loop for each child term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following code. I used the relation operator AND, referenced the var ($this_term) that contained get_queried_object(); to set the taxonomy in the tax_query and adjusted the term field in the tax_query.

```
 $this_term = get_queried_object();
 $args = array(
'parent' => $this_term->term_id,
'orderby' => 'slug',
'hide_empty' => false
 );
 $child_terms = get_terms( $this_term->taxonomy, $args );
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($child_terms as $term) {

 // List the child topic
 echo '<li><h3><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $this_term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>'; 

 // Get posts from that child topic  
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'kb',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $this_term->taxonomy,
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => array( $term->slug )
    )
  )
) );

 // List the posts
 if($query->have_posts()) {
      while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
           <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
      endwhile;
 } else  { echo "no posts";}


 // close our <li>
 echo '</li>';
 } //end foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another query that will find the posts associated with each child term, the post-containing `<div>` needs to be changed to an `<li>` since it is still inside the `<ul>`. You might want to indent the posts underneath the child term link. This should point you in the general direction:

```
foreach ($child_terms as $term) {

     // List the child topic
     echo '<li><h3><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $this_term->taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>'; 

     // Get posts from that child topic
     $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'yourposttype',
          'tax_query' => array(
                   'taxonomy' => $term->term_id,
                   'field' => 'term_id',
                   'terms' => 'terms'
          )
     );
     $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
     // List the posts
     if($query->have_posts()):
          while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
               <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
          ehdwhile;
     endif;

     // close our <li>
     echo '</li>';
 } //end foreach
```

I am not as familiar with taxonomy queries, so the `tax_query` portion may need to be adjusted and I welcome edits. The key is you need a query to grab the posts you need, and once you have a Loop you can then use `the_permalink` etc. as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to find a solution as listed above.